# Paragraph direction missing in Adobe illustrator CC 2018

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I can't find paragraph direction tool under paragraph panel. I also can't find language options under type menu. Any ideas?

For clarification:

Paragraph panel for me:

[image]

which should be:

[image]

and type menu:

[image]

which should be:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems more like an Adobe help question.

Comment: I agree with you in a way, but I have read everything in Adobe help and it did not help. I was hoping someone has an idea here.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've chosen the Indic option in the Preferences, you have to both define a paragraph style and/or character style using the RTL option, AND select that para in the paragraph tool and choose "Middle-Easter & South Asian Every-Line Composer" for this to work - I got reversed direction flow, and with the "RTL character" in Character Style, also got fully reversed characters without any trouble - I've not any Middle Eastern fonts to test with - but this was my result:

[image]

I've limited knowledge of RTL languages, so I can't help any further than this - but I hope this does help some!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the knowledge mentioned here in this article: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/arabic-hebrew.html

It says that this option has now moved to "Preferences" screen.

Although on mine, it does not let me check the "Indic design option" as if it's disabled.

[image: "Preferences" screen with Language Options]

Comment: Yes I have read this page buddy, I have actually attached a picture from the very same page in my question. The paragraph direction tool is useful when there is a combination of RTL and LTR words in the text. Since they eliminated this tool, I think there must be another way of fixing this.
The show indic options will enable "middle eastern every-line composer" in the paragraph panel, and it enables you to type RTL, but if you include LTR words it will be moved to the end of the line.

Comment: It's probably in the "Indic" checkbox which may be available on only some Illustrator language versions. That's the only thing I can think of because when I enable the Asian option I can see more buttons on my paragraph panel appear.

Comment: And I can tell you that you get to choose *either* the Indic **or** the East Asian option, but they toggle - so choose one, the other de-selects.